# Would like to confirm understanding of default behaviour of importing index.js with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, import, create-react-app

Trying to understand while using create react app why if a folder contains an index.js and you want to import it, then you only specify the folder name.

I was curious to know where this is configured to automatically know to look for index.js by default?

This question was previously linked to another post but that post wasn't clear enough for me to understand. From what I gather this is my understanding and I'd like to confirm if it's correct.

My understanding is that webpack which I know runs under the hood for create-react-app is configured to by default import index.js - is this correct? I guess the configuration for this is hidden away when using create-react-app.

Does this just apply to projects built with webpack then?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration works like this:
In the `create-react-app` build all code files should be under the `/source` directory. All static files should be under the `/public` directory, and they can be referenced from base url(for example: if I have a file `/public/my-image.png`, I can use it in my JSX with `<img src = '/my-image.png`.

To answer your question, this is not just with `create-react-app`, but with any JavaScript project. If a folder has a `index.js` file, you don't have to specify `./dir/index.js` and instead can do `./dir`, which looks for a file called `index.js`.

Comment: You mean any JS project? even a vanilla one? or are you talking about React projects? I wonder how would a vanilla JS project with files imported from different folders know by default to get index,js? where would this be configured?